# Operación % en template Django

Tags: django

Necesito realizar esta simple operación en Django como se detalla en este código de PHP con Laravel:

```
 @php
    $a = 0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($images as $image)
    @if($a % 2 == 0)
    <li class="grid-item">  <!--<li class="grid-item2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid"src="{{ route('image.file',['filename' => $image->image_path]) }}" />
    </li>
    @php
    $a = $a+1;
    @endphp

    @else
    <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2">  <!--<li class="grid-item2 grid-item--width2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid"src="{{ route('image.file',['filename' => $image->image_path]) }}" />
    </li>
    @php
    $a = $a+1;
    @endphp
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

Simplemente lo que hace es entrar en uno u otro if cada vez que el foreach hace una pasada usando numeros pares e impares. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora y no me a rasultado:

```
 {% with number=0 %}
          {{number}}
          {% endwith%}


          {% for photography in photographies.all%}
          {{number}}
          {% if number|div:2 == 0.0 %}
          {{number|div:2}}


          <li class="grid-item">
            <!--<li class="grid-item2">-->
            <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
          </li>


          {{number|add:1}}
          {% endif %}
          {{number|add:1}}
          {% if number|div:2 != 0.0 %}
          {{number|div:2}}
          <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
            <!--<li class="grid-item2 grid-item--width2">-->
            <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
          </li>
          {{ number|add:1 }}

          {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
```

Estas son pruebas la verdad este código no funciona solo entra siempre en uno de los dos if ya use django-mathfilters pero parece no tener lo que necesito que es el % para sacar resto ademas que en cada pasada el contenido de la variable number se borra y vuelve a cero, quizas existe otra alternativa para realizar esto mismo. Estoy adentrandome en esto de Django de antemano agradezco por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto. Pude resolver este tema de la siguiente manera

```
 <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <!--<div id="grid" class="grid2">-->

    {% for photography in photographies.all%}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 == True %}
    <li class="grid-item">
      <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
    </li>
    {% else %}

    <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
      <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Pues necesitaba usar un contador dentro del mismo if asi:

```
 {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 == True %}
```